# Memory leak in SemClipboardManager class

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm using LeakCanary to debug memory leaks in my app, but there is a strage memory leak detected (I think it is generating in Acitvities which have EditText in them). Following is the screenshot of the leak.
I've read the thread at github of LeakCanary and someone recommended following piece of code in onDestory method , but that too didn't work for me.

```
  private void handleSemManagerMemoryLeak(Activity activity) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("samsung")) {
                Object systemService = activity.getSystemService(Class.forName("com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager"));
                Field mContext = systemService.getClass().getDeclaredField("mContext");
                mContext.setAccessible(true);
                mContext.set(systemService, null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { //ignored }
        }
    }
```

Leak report:

[image]

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: no unfortunately